# Python extracting first matching instance from multiple files

Tags: python, text, for-loop, fileoutputstream

I have written a code which opens multiple files in a directory and prints only the first instance of match of required text from each file as output.

Now I want this output in a file. Doing it simply by putting `print >> file.txt,...` or `.write` or `csv.write` inside loop will not serve the purpose.

My code is:

```
import re, os, csv, sys

path = "D:\\"
in_files = os.listdir(path)
moldesc = ['Match1', 'Match2']

for f in in_files:
    file = os.path.join(path, f)
    text = open(file, "r")
    for line in text:
        if moldesc[0] in line:
            Text1 = line.split()[-1]          
        if moldesc[1] in line:
            Text2 = line.split()[-1]
            print f, Text1, Text2               # I WANT THIS OUTPUT IN A FILE
            break
    text.close()

print "We are extraction done !!!"
```

Comment: When you write `print >> output, "some text"`, `output` should be an open file (or other file-like object), not a filename.

Comment: You'll get a `NameError` if `moldesc[1] in line` is true and `moldesc[0] in line` isn't... (The first time at least - otherwise, it may be Text1 is set from a line that's completely got nothing to do with the line that Text2 is being set for... [eg - subtly incorrect results)) Also, it doesn't seem to matter what match you get, you're always taking the last word from the line? You might as well just have `if any(m in line for m in ['Match1', 'Match2']): ...`

Comment: @DzinX Yes agreed print >> output, should have open file named "output" in w mode but still in currant script it then writes only output for matching  from only first file in directory whereas i want fist matching instance from all files in directory...

Comment: @Jon Clements Ya i am matching different words and getting last word from the line and trying to print these words....so program is working fine. But i want to take this output in a file. Which i am not able to do. Also remember i am using multiple files as input.

Comment: So - Text1 is *always before* Text2 and the output of the last words of lines 36 (text1) and 3900 (text2) [just making those up] is the expected output?

Comment: @Jon Clements yes. i have also uploaded specific example if you want to have look at http://filecloud.io/o9xcvji1 please suggest a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you managed to open a file for reading, that's just one step away from opening a file for writing.

```
out = open(outfile, "w") 
for f in in_files:
    ...
    output_string = "{},{},{}\n".format(f, HOMO, LUMO)
    out.write(output_string)
```

Comment: output_string = "{},{},{}\n".format(f, HOMO, LUMO)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: wow, are you using python 2.5?  you can use output_string = "%s,%s,%s" % (f, text1, text2)

Comment: should be, make sure you close the file, if your still having problems, post the code with the question.

Comment: that was fantastic worked as magic for me simply closing file worked...many thanks